# Why should i use summary, and what can i get from these?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm studying deep-learning and tensorboard, almost example code use summaries.

1. I wonder that why I need to use Variables summaries.
2. Their are a many type of data for summary like min, max, mean, variation, etc. 
   What should I use in a typical situation?
3. How to analyze and What can i get from these summary graph?

thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an awesome video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4) on Tensorboard that describes almost everything about Tensorboard (Graph, Summaries etc.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Variable summaries (scalar, histogram, image, text, etc) help track your model through the learning process. For example, tf.summary.scalar('v_loss', validation_loss) will add one point to the loss curve each time you call the summary op, thus give you a rough idea whether the model has converged and when to stop.
2. It depends on your variable type. For values like loss, tf.summary.scalar shows the trend across epochs; for variables like weights in a layer, it would be better to use tf.summary.histogram, which shows the change of entire distribution of weights; I typically use tf.summary.image and tf.summary.text to check the images / texts my model generates over different epochs.
3. The graph shows your model structure and the size of tensors flowing through each op. I found it hard at the beginning to organise ops nicely in the graph presentation, and I learnt a lot about variable scope from that. The other answer provides [a link for a great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4) for beginners.